# Navigation Back Button does not show on IOS 6

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, ios6

I had an app that worked just fine util now, when I am trying to run it on IOS 6.
Now it seems the back button on the navigation controller does not appear.
I tried :

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
```

In the view, there is only the nav title, but I cannot go back to the previous view.
Any suggestions  .. ?

Comment: did you mean that your apps is just fine, until you update your iOS into iOS 6?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Storyboards? If so, make sure you have the View embedded in Navigation Controller. If you are not using it, let me know.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!. I can't get the question you are asking, and I guess others neither. Could you please edit your question in a way that makes your problem clear? Here are some hints how to get better answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I still don't know if your using storyboards on your app? Did you create the navigation controller from raw code or did you use storyboards for your app.